# Losing data from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm slicing 3 elements from an array and storing them to another array

```
array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
rows = 3;
```

Here is my method

```
getVertWallStruct = (array, rows) => {
    let i = 1,
        storageArr = [],
        data = [];

    for (let k = 0; k < rows*2; k++) { // everything's ok here
      storageArr.push(array.slice(k*rows, (k+1)*rows));
    }

    data = storageArr;

    console.log("storageArr - ", storageArr, " , array - ", array, " , data - ", data);

    return data;
  }
```

In this case storageArr will consist of empty arrays (as far as data). But when I delete line with **data = storageArr;** I get:

```
storageArr =  [ //storageArr should look like this in the end
  [1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [0, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]
]
```

Why do I lose values?

Update:
Even when I copy-pasted code from one of the answers - method returns **empty** data. Why?

Code looks like:

```
getVertWallStruct = (array, rows) => {
    console.log(array, rows); //okay here
   
    let iterator = array.values()
    let out = []
    for (let i = 0;i < ~~(array.length / rows); i++){
      out.push([iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value])
    }
    console.log(out); //empty ???
    
    return out;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: `arr = array` is pretty pointless here. Just rename the argument. Likewise so is `data = storageArr`. Just `return storageArr` directly.

Comment: Remember in JavaScript `x = y` for objects **does not copy the object**, it means that `x` and `y` refer to the *same object*.

Comment: Why `k < rows*2` when you're grouping them in chunks of 3? Should that be `k < rows * 3`? Or are you intending to use pairs but getting triplets?

Comment: It's empty because you never touch it directly, you declare it as an empty array, then throw that empty array out and make it an alias for `storageArr`. Can you explain what the code does in its current form and how that's incorrect? It's not clear what you mean by "lose values".

Comment: @LirysJH what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JothamArdel, "//storageArr should look like this in the end"

Comment: @LirysJH, I tested your code and it works well, I don't understand your issue.

Comment: Edited one more time because of this weird problem of losing values

Comment: Added output screenshot

Comment: I updated my answer below, this looks ok?

Comment: @NVRM, I don't know why but output data is empty...I added screenshot to the post

Comment: I am not sure what's going on, here is a capture from my side: https://imgur.com/4h1Dbun

Answer (score 2):

A possible way to do that, using an Array iterator:

> The values() method returns a new Array Iterator object that contains
> the values for each index in the array.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

```js
const array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
let iterator = array.values()
let out = []
for (let i = 0;i < ~~(array.length / 3);i++){
  out.push([iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value])
}
console.log(out)
```

---

Update, this looks to works fine:

> Update: Even when I copy-pasted code from one of the answers - method
> returns empty data. Why?

```js
getVertWallStruct = (array, rows) => {
    let iterator = array.values()
    let out = []
    for (let i = 0;i < ~~(array.length / rows); i++){
      out.push([iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value, iterator.next().value])
    }
    return out;
  };

console.log(
  getVertWallStruct([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 3)
)
```

Comment: Why `i <= ~~((array.length / 3) - 1` and not this `i < ~~((array.length / 3) `?

Comment: You are right, I was using `<=`, corrected to simplify, thanks.

Comment: Problem still occurs. Method returns empty data

Answer (score 0):

Use a reduce, push a blank array into the accumulator every time the index is divisible by the number of rows. Push the current item into the last array in the accumulator.

```js
const array = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

const rowify = (array, rows) => array.reduce((results, current, index) => {
  if (index % rows === 0) {
    results.push([]);
  }
  results[results.length - 1].push(current);
  return results;
}, []);

console.log(rowify(array, 3));
```